# Can I use `WithCredentialsFile` with a ServiceAccount token?

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I have trouble authenticating with my GCP ServiceAccount. Because my pod defines `spec.ServiceAccountName`, the SA gets mounted to my pod and is available under `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`

```
cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
# Shows 1185 random chars
```

The golang storage SDK has a `WithCredentialsFile` ([see docs](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/option#WithCredentialsFile)). This function takes a JSON file. Is there any way I can convert the token mounted into my pod into a JSON credentials file?

Comment: As is, this question doesn't make much sense, spec.ServiceAccountName defines a kubernetes serviceAccount, not a GCP one. The only situation where these are linked (afaik) is in GKE, in which case you can just use the default credentials via storage.NewClient(ctx).

Comment: Why do you need a token? Why don't you use workload identity federation?